# index 0 out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I have just started Java.I have some C++ experience.I want to implement a stack class.Here is my class:

```
public class stack {
   private static int MAX;
   stack(int a)
    {
       MAX = a;//input max size of stack
    }
  stack()
  {
     MAX = 1000;//default max size stack is 1000
  }
   private int[] my_stack = new int[MAX];
   private int top = 0;
   public void push(int x)
   {
       if (this.top > MAX)System.out.println("OVERFLOW");
       else my_stack[this.top++] = x;//ERROR LINE
   }
   public void pop()
   {
       if (this.top == 0)System.out.println("TOO LOW");
       else this.top--;
   }
   public int top()
   {
     return my_stack[this.top - 1];
   }
}
```

The error says:

```
Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at stack.push(stack.java:17)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)
```

Can anyone explain me the problem?

Comment: The problem is the initialization order, my_stack is initialized when the constructor is not called yet, thus MAX is 0 at that time. Initialize my_stack in the constructor after setting MAX value.

Comment: Also `MAX` shouldn't be `static` since each `stack` should have its own `MAX` value.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh , you're right.

Comment: @Rocco i dont get it

Comment: @Rooco how is my_stack initialized when the constructor is not called yet?I thought first thing called when an object is created is the constructor.

Comment: Check the solution, maybe it's clearer, the constructor is the first thing called ... after the inline initializers .. and other things.

Answer (score 1):

Here some minimal changes, explained with comments

```
public class stack {
   private int max;  //Removed static here and changed to lowercase, this is an instance field
   stack(int a)
    {
       max = a; //input max size of stack
       my_stack = new int[max]; //Here the value of max is initialized an you can use it
    }
  stack()
  {
     this(1000); //Call other constructor, just to avoid duplicate code
  }
   private int[] my_stack;  //You can't initialize the array there, since you don't know the size yet
   private int top = 0;

   public void push(int x)
   {
       if (this.top >= max)System.out.println("OVERFLOW"); //You must check with >=, not just > since the maximum index is max-1
       else my_stack[this.top++] = x;//ERROR LINE
   }
   public void pop()
   {
       if (this.top == 0)System.out.println("TOO LOW");
       else this.top--;
   }
   public int top()
   {
     return my_stack[this.top - 1];
   }
}
```

Comment: You used my_stack in the constructor and after that you declared my_stack.Does the order not matter?

Comment: @CosminAndrei In case of fields it doesn't matter, in case of *local variables* it does. Initialization of fields happens at start of every constructor (after `super` call). So in your case `stack(){ MAX = 1000;} private int[] my_stack = new int[MAX];` is same as if you would write `stack(){ super(); {my_stack = new int[MAX];} MAX = 1000;} private int[] my_stack;` so as you see assigning `1000` to `MAX` happens *after* initialization of `my_stack` which uses *default* value of `MAX` which is `0`.

Comment: @CosminAndrei no, as PShemo correctly said, it's a member of the class, so it's visible to all methods and constructors regardless of the declaration order (that is somewhat relevant for initialization anyway: if you declare two fields and initialize them out of the constructor then they are initialized in declaration order).